# filter pipe for every component

Tags: angular, pipe, angular2-template

I am building an angular4 app. I have written custom filter pipe. I can use it in only one component such that in every ngFor my property name is different for example
1) in student component, I used filter pipe:

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let studentReport of studentReports | filter: term">
   </li>
</ul>
```

2) in statistic component I have this and I want to use my filter pipe also in here:

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let statReport of statReports">
   </li>
</ul>
```

my custom pipe is like this

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
   name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

   transform(studentReports: any, term: any): any {

       //check search term if undefined
       if(term == undefined) return studentReports;
       //return updated array

       return studentReports.filter(function(studentReport) {
           return studentReport.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())
       });
   }

}
```

I have to change the values to something that i can use it in every component..

I will be appreciate if anyone help me out.

Comment: please describe your problem, you just described what you want and not whats wrong

Comment: Just a heads-up that this is bad-practice: there is a good reason that Angular does not come with a `FilterPipe` or `OrderByPipe`. Read this: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#no-filter-pipe. You should do ordering and filtering in the component, not the template.

Comment: @mtx thank you for commenting. in this article it says "The Angular team and many experienced Angular developers strongly recommend moving filtering and sorting logic into the component itself."  .. The question is how can i move filtering to component with the search input?

Comment: you can club the pipe along with a directive that will make it pluggable

Comment: @VugarAhmadov a quick plnkr example how moving filtering to the component could be done: http://plnkr.co/edit/eil1CiqlFrjDyBtUt6iQ Obviously there are a lot of different ways to implement something like this!

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether it's recommended or not, here is a generic pipe you can use:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterBy'
})

export class FilterByPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args: string[]): any[] {

    if (!args[0]) {
      return value;
    }
    else if (value) {

      return value.filter(item => {

        // TODO: Allow args[1] to be null, therefore searching in all object properties
        if ((typeof item[args[1]] === 'string' || item[args[1]] instanceof String) && (item[args[1]].toLowerCase().indexOf(args[0].toLowerCase()) !== -1)) {
          return true;
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```